# read xml content and add some numbers with php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file but through php I would like to make some changes only for some products (each item has its own id.
Let me explain better on some products I would like to add the shipping cost with the price and at the item use grid put from 1 to 0.

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <sku>35</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>test sku</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>test manufacturer</manufacturer>
    <ean>800000000000</ean>
    <title><![CDATA[title test]]></title>
    <description><![CDATA[description</description>
    <product_price_vat_inc>8.08</product_price_vat_inc>
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>4.99</shipping_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>2842</quantity>
    <brand><![CDATA[Finder]]></brand>
    <merchant_category><![CDATA[Home/test category]]></merchant_category>
    <product_url><![CDATA[https://www.example.com]]></product_url>
    <image_1><![CDATA[https://www.example.com]]></image_1>
    <image_2><![CDATA[]]></image_2>
    <image_3><![CDATA[]]></image_3>
    <image_4><![CDATA[]]></image_4>
    <image_5><![CDATA[]]></image_5>
    <retail_price_vat_inc/>
    <product_vat_rate>22</product_vat_rate>
    <shipping_vat_rate>22</shipping_vat_rate>
    <manufacturer_pdf/>
    <ParentSKU/>
    <parent_title/>
    <Cross_Sell_Sku/>
    <ManufacturerWarrantyTime/>
    <use_grid>1</use_grid>
    <carrier>DHL</carrier>
    <shipping_time>2#3</shipping_time>
    <carrier_grid_1>DHL</carrier_grid_1>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_1>2#3</shipping_time_carrier_grid_1>
    <carrier_grid_2/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_2/>
    <carrier_grid_3/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_3/>
    <carrier_grid_4/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_4/>
    <carrier_grid_5/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_5/>
    <DisplayWeight>0.050000</DisplayWeight>
    <free_return/>
    <min_quantity>1</min_quantity>
    <increment>1</increment>
    <sales>0</sales>
    <eco_participation>0</eco_participation>
    <shipping_price_supplement_vat_inc>0</shipping_price_supplement_vat_inc>
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 1):

You XML is a little large so let's strip it down for the example:

```
$xmlString = <<<'XML'
<Products>
  <Product>
    <sku>35</sku>
    <title><![CDATA[title test]]></title>
    <use_grid>1</use_grid>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <sku>42</sku>
    <title><![CDATA[title test two]]></title>
    <use_grid>1</use_grid>
  </Product>
</Products>
XML;
```

DOM is a standard API for XML manipulation. PHP supports it and Xpath expressions for fetching nodes.

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', "UTF-8");
// $document->load($xmlFile);
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
// $xpath for fetching node using expressions
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate "Product" nodes with a specific "sku" child
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//Product[sku="35"]') as $product) {
    // output sku and title for validation
    var_dump(
        $xpath->evaluate('string(sku)', $product),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $product)
    );
    // iterate the "use_grid" child elements
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('./use_grid', $product) as $useGrid) {
        // output current value
        var_dump(
            $useGrid->textContent
        );
        // change it
        $useGrid->textContent = "0";
    }
}
echo "\n\n", $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
string(2) "35"
string(10) "title test"
string(1) "1"


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <sku>35</sku>
    <title><![CDATA[title test]]></title>
    <use_grid>0</use_grid>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <sku>42</sku>
    <title><![CDATA[title test two]]></title>
    <use_grid>1</use_grid>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

#### Xpath::evaluate()

`Xpath::evaluate()` fetches nodes using an Xpath expression. The result type depends on the expression. A location path like `//Product[sku="35"]` will return a list of nodes (`DOMNodeList`). However Xpath functions inside the can return a scalar value - `string(sku)` will return the text content of the first `sku` child node as a string or an empty string.

#### DOMNode::$textContent

Reading `$node->textContent` will return all the text inside a node - including inside descendant elements.

Writing it replaces the content while taking care of the escaping.

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly.
I wanted to ask you one last thing,
since I have to edit several sku, in order to avoid writing many lines is it possible to use a csv file where in the first column I enter the sku and in the second column I enter the values I want to change?